# Certificado AutoFirmado Volley Android

Tags: java, android, ssl, certificado

Tengo el siguiente método que realiza una llamada a un servicio por `volley`

```
public GenericController(boolean flag) {


   if(flag) {
       objectRequest = new ObjetRequest(1, "", BaseRequest.class, "", new Response.Listener<BaseRequest>() {
           @Override
           public void onResponse(BaseRequest response) {

               // response
           }
       }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
           @Override
           public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
               // Error
           }
       }) {
           @Override
           public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
               Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
               params.put("sessionToken", Globals.getSessionToken());
               params.put("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");

               return params;
           }
       };
   }
    else {
       objectRequest = new ObjetRequest<>(1, "", BaseRequest.class, "", new Response.Listener<BaseRequest>() {
           @Override
           public void onResponse(BaseRequest response) {

               // response
           }
       }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
           @Override
           public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
               // Error
           }
       });

   }
}
```

Que utiliza:

```
 public void servicio_Get_Bancos(final Context context, String request, final Response.Listener<Get_Bancos_IFIS> listener, final Response.ErrorListener errorListener) {
    int method = Request.Method.POST;
    String serviceURL = URLLocal;
    String req = "";
    try {
        req = request;
        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context, null);
        objectRequest = new ObjetRequest(method, serviceURL, Get_Bancos_IFIS.class, req, listener, errorListener);
        objectRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(TIME_OUT, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
        queue.add(objectRequest);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Logger logger = Logger.getAnonymousLogger();
        logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "an exception was thrown", e);
    }
}
```

El problema es que a la url que le estoy apuntando tiene un certificado autofirmado , y al intentar usar el servicio , el mismo siempre se va con el listener de error y en el logcat no vea mensaje de error , alguna forma de ignorar los certificados o solucionar este tema?

Comment: esto te puede ayudar https://newfivefour.com/android-trust-all-ssl-certificates.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolvi colocando esta Clase para desabilitar los certificados

```
public  class NukeSSLCerts {
protected static final String TAG = "NukeSSLCerts";

public static void nuke() {
    try {
        TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[] {
                new X509TrustManager() {
                    public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                        X509Certificate[] myTrustedAnchors = new X509Certificate[0];
                        return myTrustedAnchors;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {}

                    @Override
                    public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {}
                }
        };

        SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
        sc.init(null, trustAllCerts, new SecureRandom());
        HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory());
        HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier() {
            @Override
            public boolean verify(String arg0, SSLSession arg1) {
                return true;
            }
        });
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
}
```

}

Se deberan usar solo para desarrollo , nunca para Produccion

En la clase donde esta el servicio solo instancie una clase de estas y llamo al metodo `nuke()`